# html() and click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I initially got this code and all works well:

```
<div class="rm">
        <button id="sub" type="submit">
            <span>Registo</span>
        </button>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rm>#sub").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formdata = $("#custom").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "dojo/insert.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formdata,
                success: function(data) {
                    switch (data.livre) {

                    case 'error':
                        $(".rm").html('<button id="sub"  type="submit"><span>Rever</span></button>');
                        break;                    

                    default:
                        $('#paginas').delay(50).load('profile_empresa_3.php');          
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;              
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem now. When i add `$(".rm").html("")` with a button with the same id. If i click in this new button the page is reloaded. My question is. If the button added has the same id, why the click handler is not repeated ?

thanks

Comment: `ID`-s should be unique. Better use the same `class` for your buttons

Comment: @Zoltan: in the pasted code, the new button replaces the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you bind the event handler to `$(".rm > #sub")`, the new element does not exist yet, so jQuery cannot bind the handler to it.

You could either rebind the event handler, or bind it to `$('.rm')` instead and use event delegation (using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) :

```
$('.rm').on('click', '#sub', function() { // or use button instead of #sub
   //...
});
```

But instead of replacing the whole element, it seems you could just change its text content:

```
$('#sub span').text('Rever');
// or
$('.rm button span').text('Rever');
```

---

Also note that IDs are supposed to be unique, having two elements in the DOM with the same ID is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

An id should be unique across a page.

To add the same action for all new dynamically created buttons, you need to do something like:

```
 $(".rm > .sub").live("click",function(event) {
....
```

But without using the same id, use a class instead as I have above.

Comment: in jquery 1.7, live method apparently is deprecated.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot! .delegate then!

Answer (score 1):

The `click` function will traverse the DOM, and bind the event to all elements that exist *at that point in time*. You are creating a new DOM element later, which does not get bound.

To make this work out the way you want, see the jQuery documentation for the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.

The resulting change would look like:

```
$('#sub').live('click', function(event) {
    //your implementation
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the events are bound in the unique DOM object regardless from id, when you remove the initial button and replace with one with same id the event bound to the button is gone.

What you can do is declare the event function in a variable and when you re-make your button, assign the event again to it.

Your code would be:

```
var btnEvent =  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $("#custom").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "dojo/insert.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data) {
            switch (data.livre) {

            case 'error': {
                $(".rm").html('<button id="sub" type="submit" onclick="return btnEvent(event)"><span>Rever</span></button>');

            } break;                    

            default:
                $('#paginas').delay(50).load('profile_empresa_3.php');          
                break;
            }
        }
    });
return false;              
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rm>#sub").click(btnEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.on()` instead of `.click()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/